# How to generate dynamic PDF invoices from a react APP and/or Express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm building a simple React app with an express/node API that allows users make orders for production. I need to find a way to generate dynamic PDF invoices based on the order data - similar to what a webshop would make. Printing is important, so it must be PDF. I've tried working with print stylesheet, but it's simply a mess.

I've been searching google thin, but can't seem to find any solution that allows me to design the PDF so it looks like a regular invoice. Any ideas how someone could achieve this with react or node? Preferably without using third party services.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf

Comment: This only seem to help reading existing PDFs. I need to generate new ones with dynamic data. Thanks though. This may proof useful too

Comment: Google is your friend: https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to install a service and call it you can try [JSReports](https://jsreport.net/).  This would be the quickest solution, from your backend node code call the api passing it data and a template name you create in their designer and get back bytes which you can then stream down to the client.  I have used this solution before and it works very well.

If you are not willing to install a service you can still try to use JSReports but embed it in you node app using express with [this](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-express).  I have not tried this solution but the project still seems active and the last release was this year.

#### Update

Actually JSReports directly supports being embedded in express so you don't have to use that project, [here are the docs on their site](https://jsreport.net/learn/adapting-jsreport).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [easyinvoice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyinvoice).

- you fetch the data and get the data. Then, create this function

  ```
  import easyinvoice from "easyinvoice";


  // I fetch booking and pass it as arg
  const downloadInvoice = async (booking) => {
    const data = {
      documentTitle: "INVOICE", //Defaults to INVOICE
      currency: "USD",
      taxNotation: "vat", //or gst
      marginTop: 25,
      marginRight: 25,
      marginLeft: 25,
      marginBottom: 25,
      logo: "link to show on your invoice",
      sender: {
        company: "Hotel",
        address: "4 W 13th St",
        zip: "10011",
        city: "New York",
        country: "United States",
      },
      client: {
        company: `${booking.user.name}`,
        address: `${booking.user.email}`,
        zip: "",
        city: `Check In: ${new Date(booking.checkInDate).toLocaleString(
          "en-US"
        )}`,
        country: `Check In: ${new Date(booking.checkOutDate).toLocaleString(
          "en-US"
        )}`,
      },
      invoiceNumber: `${booking._id}`,
      invoiceDate: `${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString("en-US")}`,
      products: [
        {
          quantity: `${booking.daysOfStay}`,
          description: `${booking.room.name}`,
          tax: 0,
          price: booking.room.pricePerNight,
        },
      ],
      bottomNotice:
        "add message",
    };

    const result = await easyinvoice.createInvoice(data);
    easyinvoice.download(`invoice_${booking._id}.pdf`, result.pdf);
  };
  ```
- add a click handler to a button

  ```
     <button
            className="btn btn-success mx-2"
            onClick={() => downloadInvoice(booking)}
          >
            // this is fontawesome class
            <i className="fa fa-download"></i>
     </button>
  ```